# Story about group of kids one of whom is called "Boomer" (and dies)

Tags: story-identification

My brother has asked me to pass on a query for him re a book he would have read in 1970s or possibly very early 1980s.
He thought there was more than one book and it followed the adventures of a small group of kids who moved between worlds, fought pirates and other challenges, etc. One of the kids was called Boomer and in one of the books, Boomer died. That's all he could recall, but he's very keen to locate them again. Any help greatly appreciated.